# Changing single cell color with ngClass

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a hard time here with ngClass as I'm new to angular. I've got a table set up that generates rows dynamically from a database using ng-repeat, with span and input elements that hide/show based on editing/not editing the cell (imagine microsoft excel).

```
<tr>
  <th class="row_head">Row Title</th>
  <td ng-click="edit = true" ng-repeat="item1 in JSONobject | orderBy: '_id'" >
     <span ng-hide="edit">{{ item1.key.value1 }}</span>
     <input ng-show="edit" class="editing-cell" ng-model="item1.key.value1" ng-blur="edit = false; " ng-enter="saveData(item1._id, item1.key); edit = false" type="text" />
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th class="row_head">Row Title</th>
  <td ng-click="edit = true" ng-repeat="item2 in JSONobject | orderBy: '_id'" >
     <span ng-hide="edit">{{ item2.key.value2 }}</span>
     <input ng-show="edit" class="editing-cell" ng-model="item2.key.value2" ng-blur="edit = false; " ng-enter="saveData(item2._id, item2.key); edit = false" type="text" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

and so on.

I want to set it so on blur (data not saved) the cell turns red, and alternatively on save - turns green.

The issue i'm running into with ngClass is if i just go with:

```
ng-class="{'saved': saved, 'notSaved': notSaved}"
```

It changes the background color of EVERY cell, rather than just the cell edited.

I do not have this issue with ng-hide and ng-show, even though they appear to be a similar scenario with changing the boolean value of 'edit'. They still stick to their specific cell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's changing the color on every cell because you're performing this action on every cell.  Do you have any way to uniquely identify the cells within the DOM?

Comment: it changed the background color of every cell when i edit 1 single cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into how form styling works.

**The following classes are added to, or removed from, input fields**:

```
ng-untouched The field has not been touched yet
ng-touched The field has been touched
ng-pristine The field has not been  modified yet
ng-dirty The field has been modified
ng-valid The field content is valid
ng-invalid The field content is not valid
ng-valid-key One key for each validation. Example: ng-valid-required, useful when there are more than one thing that must be validated
ng-invalid-key Example: ng-invalid-required
```

**The following classes are added to, or removed from, forms:**

```
ng-pristine No fields has not been modified yet
ng-dirty One or more fields has been modified
ng-valid The form content is valid
ng-invalid The form content is not valid
ng-valid-key One key for each validation. Example: ng-valid-required, useful when there are more than one thing that must be validated
ng-invalid-key Example: ng-invalid-required
The classes are removed if the value they represent is false.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
<style>
form.ng-pristine {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
form.ng-dirty {
    background-color:pink;
}
</style>
<body ng-app="">

<form name="myForm">
<p>Try writing in the input field:</p>

<input name="myName" ng-model="myName" required>

<p>The form gets a "ng-dirty" class when the form has been modified, and will therefore turn pink.</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it changes the background of the input element. What i'm trying to do is basically changing the background color of the td element based on whether the input element was closed via the enter key (saving the data), or on blur (not saved)

Comment: My pleasure, if you have any other concern please feel free to ask and if this answer works out, please remember to tick the answer. A lot answers do not get closed out that are working answers. Cheers!

Comment: i think i'm on the right track. i essentially want to change the background color by triggering ng-dirty on blur. and then the same idea, but different color when pressing enter out of the cell instead of blur.. if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was not knowing enough about custom directives. I've got it figured out now with

```
.directive('isSaved', function(){
return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.notSaved = function(){
            attr.$set('class', 'notSaved');
        };
        scope.saved = function(){
            attr.$set('class', 'saved');
        };

      }
  };
});
```